# Delete Dimension of mutlidimensional array

Tags: python, numpy

i have an array of shape

```
(512, 240, 1, 3, 3)
```

How can I get red of the last dimension. Should work with

```
np.delete
```

but cant figure out how exactly. all the examples are in 2D...

---

I think I misformulated the question. What I looked for was

```
A = A[:,:,:,0]
```

Sorry

Comment: What should be the output's shape?

Comment: What about A[:, :, :, :, 1] or A[:, :, :, :, 2] ? They give back the same shape.

Answer (score 2):

I believe `(512, 240, 1, 3, 3)` is a tuple (data you're working with) and not a shape of your array. To remove the last dimension (`3` in your case) with `numpy.delete` you can do the following:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a=np.array((512, 240, 1, 3, 3))
>>> a=np.delete(a,4)
>>> a
array([512, 240,   1,   3])
```

Remember that `numpy.delete` returns a *new array* and the original one stays unchanged. That's why I did `a=np.delete(...)`.

Comment: I am really not sure this answers the question : a.shape is (5, )

Comment: @M.Massias, okay, if `a` should be modified then just assign the return value of `np.delete`

Comment: No, I mean the first line of the question is : I have an array of shape (512, 240, 1, 3, 3). Your array, before even modifying it, is of shape (5, )

Comment: @M.Massias, there should be a mistake in the question: how can be an array of such a shape when it's supposed to be 2D?

Comment: Yes, the question is not good. I don't think OP means his array is 2D, I think he means that all the examples he can find are 2D.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by delete the last dimension, but if you want to merge the two last dimensions, you can use `np.reshape(yourArray, (512, 240, 1, 3*3))`